# iPhone Timer Frequency

Tags: iphone, timer

I am trying to use iPhone for some sort of measurement and I need an event that fires every mSec (or sooner), this event will turn on/off the LED.

I have tried a few options to make this work without any success. If I use NSTImer event, the maximum frequency I can reach is around 100Hz.

If I turn on/off the LED in a simple for loop, the frequency goes to 300Hz but that seems to be the maximum. Also it is not purely periodic, a context switch happens and I get the control back much later.

I also experimented with Mach API but no luck. Do you think is it even possible to turn on/off LED at a frequency around 1KHz.

Answer (score 2):

NSTimer has a limited resolution as you have discovered.

Apps are not designed to be real-time systems and system processes can (and do) occur from time to time which may delay processing periodically (memory alerts, system functions, etc). These may not be manifested in obvious ways for usual apps, but if you are attempting to do some intense loops then you will observe them more frequently.